# Tigase: MUG not implemented, what's next?

Tags: iphone, xmpp, tigase

I'm starting the development of a multiplayer game for iPhone/iPad and i was thinking of using Tigase as XMMP server for the game server. However it seems like Tigase not yet implement MUG XEP. Anyway MUG is too complex for the simple task i'm trying to achieve so.

Here is the game basic:

- Each Match may have up to 4 players.
- Each player may perform at any moment a move and the only game rule is to forward a packet to each player in the match that tell the move the user mades and weither or not is is a good move or not.

Here is the way i want to implement it:

- Reuse the MUC component to simulate the Multi-player room.
- Each room will have a Bot member: all packet will me addressed to that BOT directly: the BOT will check the moves (which will be basic message packets) for validity and sent the appropriate message to all Player in the room.

I think this may work. If you think this is a viable solution:

- What is the best way to write the BOT. Should i have one BOT per room? how can i detect when a new room is created so i can create the BOT?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the most simple way to do this is to build a plug-in to the MUC component. The MUC and MUG components are very similar so it provide most of the mecanism a multiplayer game needs.